# How to get node name for " * " node in Grafana graphite query in aliasByNode() funtion

Tags: grafana, graphite

In grafana i am trying to get values from all nodes using * in query.

Actual Query : [image: demo.test.*.*.observed_daily.utilization]

Data Source used : Graphite

If i use aliasByNode(2) i am expecting the node value, instead * is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The `maxSeries` reduces entire subset of metrics to "brand" new one and that metric is called literally - `Demo.test.*.*.observed_daily.utilization`. After simple split by '.' you get *.

You can avoid this behavior if you apply `aliasByNode` before any reduce/aggregation functions eg.

`maxSeries(aliasByNode(Demo.test.*.*.observed_daily.utilization, 2))`

Comment: query is displayed as alias value if above mentioned solution is applied